# Disabling the media browser private download option , showing public download as an option

Tags: media

In the media module when we upload an image it asks us how to store a file (as public or private). But I don't want to show the user these options. Moreover, the user should not see that option box and the file uploaded should be saved as public file only. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to the latest 2.x version of the [media](https://drupal.org/project/media) module and [file entity](https://drupal.org/project/file_entity) module.

This issue was addressed in https://drupal.org/node/2001074

There is now admin configuration at the file system settings page.

In my opinion the configuration ability still needs some improvement but it dos the job for now.